# Powershell - Need to take only file name with a specific pattern and ignore the rest

Tags: powershell

I have a script that read a file name from path location and then he takes only the numbers and do something with them. could be more than one file in the path

An example for file:

```
Patch_1348968.vip
Patch_1348968_v1.vip
Patch_1348968_v2.Zip
```

It takes the number 1348968.

The code that do that is:

```
$compressedfiles = Get-ChildItem -path $FilesPath\* -Include "*.vip", "*.zip", "*cab"
foreach ($file in $compressedfiles) {
$PatchNumber = ""
$PatchNumber = $file.Name -replace '.*[-_](\d+).*', '$1'
more code....
}
```

The goal is to ignore (continue to the next file) while the pattern **is not** as patch_#########
An example to files I want to ignore:
patch-8.6.22 (DA GUI CU + 1351661 + 1344344).zip

Any idea how to do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is too permissive to exclude the files that are *not* of interest.

Based on the examples, including in later comments, and your description, the following would work:

```
# Simulated Get-ChildItem output.
$compressedfiles = [System.IO.FileInfo[]] @(
  'patch-8.6.22 (DA GUI CU + 1351661 + 1344344).zip',
  'Patch_1348968.vip'
  'Patch_1348968_v1.vip', 
  'Patch_1348968_v2.Zip',
  'patch-1234567.zip',
  'patch_7654321-V9.zip'
  'patch-7654329-V10.zip',
  'patch_42424242_abc453.zip',
  'patch_42424243_copy@34.zip',
  'Patch_1348968_copy.Zip'
 )
 
foreach ($file in $compressedfiles) {
  if ($file.Name -notmatch '^patch[-_](\d+)(?:[-_][\w]+@?\d*)?\.\w{3}$') { 
    Write-Verbose -Verbose "Skipping: $($file.Name)"
    continue 
  }
  $patchNumber = $Matches[1] # Get the number that the capture group matched.
  $patchNumber # Sample output.
  # ...
}
```

The above uses the [`-notmatch` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch) and the [automatic `$Matches` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#matches) instead of [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator), because the latter returns the input string as-is if its regex operand doesn't match (while you can compare the result to see if it is the same as the input string to infer whether `-replace` found at least one match, the above strikes me as conceptually clearer).

For an **explanation of the regex** and the ability to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/SK4lGf/6).

Comment: I'm impressed, thank you very much its very helpful.
Just want to know if I want to support also for patch-###### 
and 
patch_#####-V1
What should I need to add?
I mean to support also for:
patch_######
patch_######_V1
patch_######-V1
patch-######_v1
patch-######-v1

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Bandit; please see my update, which should handle all these example correctly. I've also added a link to a rege101.com page where you can play with the regex yourself (and have it explained).

Comment: Thank you again @mklement0
Actually what I really need  is to support for patch_ or patch- plus set of numbers plus '-' or '_' and I don't care what will be the rest until the .zip (Not just V#)
Sorry for the confusion 
it could be patch_######_abc453.zip or patch-#####-copy@34.zip

Comment: I don't understand the  RegEx :(

Comment: @Bandit, it's hard to glean the exact logic from these examples, but I've updated the regex and the regex101.com page to handle the additional examples as well. One thing notable about your non-matching example is that it contains _spaces_. If that is true for all files that should be excluded, you can simply exclude those that contain spaces.

Comment: @Bandit, to understand the regex, follow the regex101.com link.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to learn it...
I don't have spaces
I have tried the rege101 with your latest update for Patch_1348968_copy.Zip and I don't have a match

Comment: What about this?
^patch[-_](\d+)[-_.].+

Comment: @Bandit, I've updated the regex again, but without a full specification of what should and shouldn't match, this back-and-forth is exhausting. If the latest update doesn't work for you, please ask a _new_ question, with a full description of what should and shouldn't match - examples alone aren't enough. The regex in your previous comment excludes valid names too - paste it into the regex101.com page to verify.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#-match-and--notmatch) operator to test if a string matches a given pattern. Extract the version number using a capture group `(...)` in the RegEx.

```sh
foreach ($file in $compressedfiles) {
    if( $file.Name -match '^patch_(\d+)' ) {
        $PatchNumber = $matches[1]
        # more code....
    }
}
```

- The condition in the `if` statement evaluates to `$true`, when the pattern matches.
- The pattern:

  - `^` makes sure we match at the start of the file name, so names like `foopatch_12345.zip` won't match.
  - `patch_` matches literally (case-insensitively by default)
  - `(` starts a capture group
  - `\d+` matches one or more digits
  - `)` ends the capture group
- For more information see the [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/qS4SdV/1).
- Using the automatic `$matches` variable, which contains the full match at index 0 and the matched values of any capture groups at subsequent indices, we extract the patch number. So `$matches[1]` is the value that matches the pattern `\d+` within the parentheses.

Comment: I don't understand why matches[1] return only the number, by default?

Comment: @Bandit Because of the capture group `(\d+)` in the RegEx. It extracts what is matched within the parentheses, which is one or more digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Include "*patch*"
```

Comment: No
I am looking for VIP,ZIP and CAB
Get-ChildItem -path $FilesPath\* -Include "*.vip", "*.zip", "*cab"
I need to ignore all the files that not the pattern like patch_######
It should ignore and take the next file in the folder